# Elfeed - Kill buffers on quit

Tags: kill-buffer, elfeed

I've been using Elfeed for some time, and I like it very much. However, there is one small thing I'd like to adjust. When leaving the search window (with `elfeed-search-quit-window` bound to `q` in the mode map), Elfeed leaves a trail of open buffers: `*elfeed-search*`, `*elfeed-log*` and `myfeeds.org` (I use `elfeed-org`).

I like the behavior of `org-agenda-exit` which checks if any files visited by the agenda have been modified, if so offers to save them, and otherwise kills them. As it turns out, this is performed by the function `org-release-buffers` in `org.el`, so I tried to adapt it for my purposes.

As I don't have a list of buffers, as Org Agenda does, I tried to use `rmh-elfeed-org-files` which is rather a list of files, so I employ `file-name-nondirectory` to get the corresponding buffer name.

My unsuccessful attempt is the following:

```el
(defun my/elfeed-search-quit-and-kill-buffers ()
  "Save the database, then kill elfeed buffers, asking the user
for confirmation when needed."
  (interactive)
  (elfeed-db-save)
  (let (buf)
    (dolist (file rmh-elfeed-org-files)
      (setq buf (file-name-nondirectory file))
      (when (and (buffer-modified-p buf)
         file
         (y-or-n-p (format "Save file %s? " file)))
    (with-current-buffer buf (save-buffer)))
      (kill-buffer buf)))
  (kill-buffer "*elfeed-log*")
  (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
```

As this is intended to be bound to the `elfeed-search-mode-map` the last `(kill-buffer (current-buffer))` kills `*elfeed-search*`.

But this fails with a `Wrong type argument: bufferp, "myfeeds.org"` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have a buffer-name, rather than an object buffer, and if you need the latter, then you can convert the buffer-name to an object buffer with `get-buffer`.  E.g., `(get-buffer "myfeeds.org")` will return the object buffer.  Some functions have the ability to use either form; however, your error message is telling you that a string buffer name is not what is sought.  I don't use elfeed, but if I had to guess, I would guess ... `(setq buf (get-buffer (file-name-nondirectory file)))` assuming that `(file-name-nondirectory file)` will give you the string name for the buffer.

Comment: @lawlist Coincidentally, I had figured that out just a couple of minutes ago. (Out of luck, I admit). I just got it to work with `(setq buf (get-file-buffer file))`. Still, thank you for your comment. And an answer of yours in these lines would be welcome and accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lawlist explained in his/her [comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45464/elfeed-kill-buffers-on-quit#comment69929_45464), Emacs distinguishes the buffer's *name* from the buffer itself. And `(file-name-nondirectory file)` got me the buffer's name, not the object. Things worked fine when this was corrected with `(setq buf (get-file-buffer file))`. In full:

```el
(defun my/elfeed-search-quit-and-kill-buffers ()
  "Save the database, then kill elfeed buffers, asking the user
for confirmation when needed."
  (interactive)
  (elfeed-db-save)
  (let (buf)
    (dolist (file rmh-elfeed-org-files)
      (setq buf (get-file-buffer file))
      (when (and (buffer-modified-p buf)
             file
             (y-or-n-p (format "Save file %s? " file)))
        (with-current-buffer buf (save-buffer)))
      (kill-buffer buf)))
  (kill-buffer "*elfeed-log*")
  (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
```